# Are timer interrupts NMI..?

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to know whether timer interrupts i.e what we see at "cat /proc/interrupts | grep timer" are NMIs Or what.

I know that watchdog timer is an NMI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally this depends on the hardware and not the kernel, you should look at the documentation of your CPU. Most of the time there are only a few NMI lines available in a CPU and they should be used as less as possible. (Only for life threatening interrupts, like the watchdog timer :))

And a quite useful read about NMI http://www.ganssle.com/articles/anmi.htm